# Styles applied to audio element work in firefox and safari, but not in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, audio, tags

I created an audio player using HTML/CSS/JS, here is a codepen containing it - https://codepen.io/terramsc/pen/YzerzYw?editors=1100

HTML:

```
<div id="player">

<div id="color-switch"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/SYyiJUa.png">
  
<div id="volume-slider-container">

  <output id="volume-output">100</output>
  <div id="volume-slider-squish"><input type="range" id="volume-slider" max="100" value="70"></div>
  <button id="mute-icon"></button>

</div>
  
<div id="audio-player-container">

  <audio src="https://assets.codepen.io/4358584/Anitek_-_Komorebi.mp3" preload="metadata" loop></audio>
  
  <button id="play-icon"></button>
  <span id="current-time" class="time">0:00</span>
  <input type="range" id="seek-slider" max="100" value="0">
  <span id="duration" class="time">0:00</span>
  
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* OVERLAY */
#color-switch {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 608px;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 38px;
    position: relative;
}
#color-switch img {
  position: absolute;
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 99;
  mix-blend-mode: lighten;
  pointer-events: none;
}
button {
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 4px;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}
/* WRAPS */
#player {
  max-height: 80px;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 608px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
}
#audio-player-container {
  --seek-before-width: 0%;
  --volume-before-width: 100%;
  --buffered-width: 0%;
  position: relative;
  max-width: 600px;
  height: 32px;
  border: 4px solid white;
  z-index: 1;
  /* background color */
  background-color: #000;
}
#volume-slider-container {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  top: -30px;
  max-width: 608px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  content-align: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 5px;
  opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
    transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}
#player:hover #volume-slider-container {
    opacity: 1;
}
#audio-player-container::before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
}
#play-icon {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  margin-left: auto; 
  margin-right: auto; 
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  transform: scale(1.2);
  z-index: 1;
  filter: invert(1);
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  background: transparent;
}
path {
  stroke: #fff;
  fill: #fff;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  object-fit: cover;
}
.time {
    width: 32px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 32px;  
    color: #fff;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
}
#current-time {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}
#duration {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}
input[type="range"] {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 32px;
    float: left;
  border-radius: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  cursor: default;
}
input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    width: 100%;
    height: 32px;
    cursor: default;
    /* COLOR AFTER */
    background-color: #000;
}
input[type="range"]::before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    left: 0;
    width: var(--seek-before-width);
    height: 32px;
    /* COLOR BEFORE */
    background-color: #fff;
    cursor: default;
}
input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: default;
}
input[type="range"]:hover::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: default;
}
input[type="range"]:active::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: default;
}
input[type="range"]::-moz-range-track {
    width: 100%;
    height: 32px;
    cursor: default;
    background-color: black;
}
input[type="range"]::-moz-range-progress {
    background-color: white;
  height: 32px;
}
input[type="range"]::-moz-focus-outer {
    border: 0;
  cursor: default;
}
input[type="range"]::-moz-range-thumb {
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: default;
}
input[type="range"]:active::-moz-range-thumb {
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: default;
}
input[type="range"]::-ms-track {
    width: 100%;
    height: 32px;
    cursor: default;
    background: transparent;
}
input[type="range"]::-ms-fill-lower {
  background-color: transparent;
  cursor: default;
}
input[type="range"]::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: transparent;
  cursor: default;
}
input[type="range"]::-ms-thumb {
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: default;
}
input[type="range"]:active::-ms-thumb {
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: default;
}
output {
    width: 18px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    color: #fff;
  float: left;
}
#volume-slider {
  float: left;
}
#volume-slider-squish {
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  float: left;
  background-color: blue;
}
#volume-slider::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  float: left;
  height: 4px;
}
#volume-slider::-moz-range-track {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  float: left;
  height: 4px;
}
#volume-slider::-ms-fill-upper {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  float: left;
  height: 4px;
}
#volume-slider::before {
    width: var(--volume-before-width);
  float: left;
  height: 4px;
}
#volume-slider-squish > input[type="range"] {
  height: 4px;
}
#volume-slider-squish > input[type="range"] {
    height: 4px;
}
#volume-slider-squish > input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    height: 4px;
}
#volume-slider-squish > input[type="range"]::before {
    height: 4px;
}
#volume-slider-squish > input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  height: 4px;
  width: 4px;
  background-color: #fff;
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}
#volume-slider-squish > input[type="range"]:hover::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  height: 4px;
  width: 4px;
    transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}
#volume-slider-squish > input[type="range"]:active::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  height: 4px;
  width: 4px;
    transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}
#volume-slider-squish > input[type="range"]::-moz-range-track {
    height: 4px;
}
#volume-slider-squish > input[type="range"]::-moz-range-progress {
    height: 4px;
}
#volume-slider-squish > input[type="range"]::-moz-focus-outer {
    height: 4px;
}
#volume-slider-squish > input[type="range"]::-moz-range-thumb {
    height: 4px;
}
#volume-slider-squish > input[type="range"]:active::-moz-range-thumb {
    height: 4px;
}
#volume-slider-squish > input[type="range"]::-ms-track {
    height: 4px;
}
#volume-slider-squish > input[type="range"]::-ms-fill-lower {
    height: 4px;
}
#volume-slider-squish > input[type="range"]::-ms-fill-upper {
  height: 4px;
}
#volume-slider-squish > input[type="range"]::-ms-thumb {
  height: 4px;
}
#volume-slider-squish > input[type="range"]:active::-ms-thumb {
  height: 4px;
}
#mute-icon {
  float: left;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  margin-top: -1px;
  background: transparent;
}
```

I tested my code in safari and Firefox, and it seems to be working properly, as seen here:
[player in firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdEDN.png)

However, when I opened it in Chrome it looks like this: [player in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buPT0.png)

There are two issues, first - a thumb on a volume slider is not visible on Firefox, but it's shown as a blue dot on Chrome, second - white progress bar is shown on Firefox, but not on Chrome.

I tried my best and modified many properties to no effect. I can't get it to work despite hours of trial end error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There are two issues, first - a thumb on a volume slider is not visible on Firefox, but it's shown as a blue dot on Chrome, second - white progress bar is shown on Firefox, but not on Chrome.

Both Chrome and Firefox codepens show a white progress bar, but no volume slider.
Your `#volume-slider` css styling hides the whole element's styling. Change it to:

```
#volume-slider {
  opacity: 1; /* now styling is visible */
  
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  transform: scaleY(5.5);
}
```

You can now play around with the slider styling, but don't forget to remove webkit styling:

```
#volume-slider-squish > input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  height: 6px;
  width: 28px;
  -webkit-appearance: none; /* remove webkit styling */
          appearance: none; /* remove webkit styling */
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-top: -1px;
  transform: scale(1);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Do this for `hover` and `active` as well.